# Firestore Security Rules: understanding match /databases/{database}/documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-security

I am having trouble wrapping my head around `match /databases/{database}/documents`, in the security rules from the official documentation:

*The match `/databases/{database}/documents` declaration specifies that rules should match any Cloud Firestore database in the project. Currently each project has only a single database named (default)*

Correct me if I am wrong, if, currently, there is only one database per project, the latter being named `default` so would it be possible to replace `{database}` by `{default}` or `default` as in `/databases/default/documents`?

If not, why?

Also, following the "any" wildcard could we replace `/databases/{database}/documents` by `/databases/{database=**}/documents`?

If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if, currently, there is only one database per project, the latter being named default so would it be possible to replace {database} by {default} or default as in /databases/default/documents?

You would replace it with "(default)".  There are no other strings that will work, currently.

> Also, following the "any" wildcard could we replace /databases/{database}/documents by /databases/{database=**}/documents?

No, that will not work. The [recursive wildcard syntax](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#recursive_wildcards) you're referring to only works for matching paths of documents when referring to collections and documents.

Currently, there is no real value in saying anything other than "/databases/{database}/documents" as the prefix of the match.  There can be only one database per project.  While the rules allow for the **concept** of more, in practice, there is never any more.  That is not likely to change any time soon.

If you have feedback about the rules system, feel free to report that to [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly.